# Cannot read encrypted password in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to connect to a Tableau Server using an encrypted password. The usual command to connect is:

```
tabcmd login -u user -p password
```

I have encrypted a password and stored it into a text file with the following script.

```
echo "strongpw" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 \
-salt -pass pass:Secret@123# > secret.txt
```

- strongpw being the string I want to encrypt
- Secret@123# being the password that is used during the encryption

Once that done, I have a secret.txt file with something like this:

```
U2FsdGVkX1/VyNZZ/RTaymM4F5DHNNG0iYapp3u3+WI=
```

I can then use the following script to decrypt my password:

```
cat secret.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 \
 -salt -pass pass:Secret@123#
```

**output: strongpw**

Finally, I created an .sh script the user might execute to connect to the server.
The script is supposed to decrypt the password and store it in the variable.

```
#bin/bash

USERNAME=test
PASSWD=`cat secret.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 \ 
-iter 100000 -salt -pass pass:Secret@123#`

tabcmd login -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWD
```

I then made my script executable with `chmod +x`

Unfortunately, when trying to running, I'm always encountering either `invalid argument` or `extra arguments given` as errors.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: please check your script with https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors

Comment: @MarcoLucidi it actually helped. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with the '-in' tag to provide the input file instead of using cat?

Comment: Hi @fbinliu, I'm not familiar with the -in tag and could not find anything on it, what is it used for?

Comment: hi @Djabone, so you can use it like: ' -in ./secret.txt ' so that you don't need to use 'cat secret.txt' to pipe the input file into the command. Also, I would strongly recommend you to store your encryption password (Secret@123#) in a strictly access-controlled file which can only be openned by you, and pipe it into the command using a variable in your Shell script, instead of the current clear-text one here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarcoLucidi for showing me shellcheck.net :)

Here's how I had to modify my .sh file to make it work:

```
#bin/bash

USERNAME=test
var=$(cat secret.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 \
 -salt -pass pass:Secret@123#)
tabcmd login -u “$USERNAME” -p “$var”
tabcmd runschedule "PMS Daily 6AM"
```

Comment: glad I helped you! ps I suggest you to follow all the advice it gives you e.g. always quote your variables ;)

Comment: Make sure you quote your variables: `tabcmd login -u "$USERNAME" -p "$var"`